# Accessing Label value in a Custom Cell

Tags: iphone, xcode5

I am new to Xcode so please be a with me. I have been able to populate my tableview using a Custom Cell, the custom cell has 3 labels on it.

I need to access the value of one of the labels (myDateLabel) when the row is selected.

For a 'standard' cell I know I could use something like:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *theValue = cell.textLabel.text;
```

but I just can't figure out how to do this when using a custom cell, any help would be appreciated, I'm sure I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code from:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *theValue = cell.textLabel.text;
```

To:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.myDateLabel.text = @"text";
```

There's a great beginner tutorial here: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick, thank you very much. The tutorial also looks great.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag property of your labels in storyboard (if you're using it) or in code when creating labels.

```
label1.tag = 1001;
label2.tag = 1002;
label3.tag = 1003;
```

Then you can enumerate through cell's subViews and check the tag of subview

```
for (UIView *subview in customCell.subviews)
    switch (subview.tag)
    {
          case 1001:
           NSString *s = [(UILabel)subview text];
           break;
    }
```